# Is there an Ansible module that helps saving iptables configuration after startups

Tags: ansible, iptables

I'm trying to use an Ansible playbook to save a current iptables rules.

Originally I would have used the command `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`.
But when trying to use that command in Playbook I'm getting the following error:

```
 "stderr_lines": [
    "Unknown arguments found on commandline"
],
"cmd": [
    "iptables-save",
    ">",
    "/etc/iptables/rules.v4"
],
```

I tried to use the `command` module and `cmd` module and they both don't work, according to Ansible documentation the [iptables module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/iptables_module.html):

> This module does not handle the saving and/or loading of rules, but rather only manipulates the current rules that are present in memory

My goal eventually is to save my firewall rules that will launch on every startup of a machine.

Have a temporary solution using a bash script that does that task if anyone have another solution any help will be much appreciated 
.

Comment: You are using the `command` module which does not support redirections and pipes. You should should use [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) in this situation. I am not 100% sure you can do exactly what you want with the dedicated iptables modules. Some people [managed that through custom module](https://engineering.nordeus.com/managing-iptables-with-ansible-the-easy-way/)

Comment: @Zeitounator I'll try to use the ```shell``` as well but i'll check the custom modules field too, thanks.

Comment: @Zeitounator can you please post an answer, ```shell``` did the trick, I can't believe I didn't thought about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Converting my comment as an answer as requested by OP)

You are using the command module which does not support redirections and pipes.

You should use [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) in this situation.

I am not 100% sure you can do exactly what you want with the dedicated `iptable` modules. [Some people managed that through a custom module](https://engineering.nordeus.com/managing-iptables-with-ansible-the-easy-way/).

Answer (score 2):

There is now the `community.general.iptables_state` module to achieve that. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/iptables_state_module.html

Note that the necessary `iptables-save` command still needs to be available on the host by installing the appropriate `iptables` or `iptables6` packages.

Comment: This is key: ```Note that the necessary iptables-save command still needs to be available on the host```. I did that using:

```- name: Install iptables-persistent
  become: yes
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
    name: iptables-persistent
    state: latest```